# cannot move out of an `Rc` error while making a singly linked stack

Tags: rust, linked-list, borrow-checker, ownership

I am trying to write a Singly Linked List in Rust such that we can only append to it's 'end'. 
eg:
if the linked list is `1->2->3->5`;
we may `push(7)` and the result would be 
`1->2->3->5->7`. 
This is the code:

```
use std::cell::{Ref, RefCell};
use std::rc::Rc;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Node {
    data: isize,
    next: Rc<Option<Node>>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct SinglyLinkedList {
    head: Rc<Option<Node>>,
    len: usize,
}

impl Node {
    fn from(data: isize) -> Self {
        Self {
            data, next:Rc::from(None)
        }
    }
}

impl SinglyLinkedList {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            head: Rc::from(None),
            len: 0,
        }
    }

    fn append(&mut self, data: isize) {
        self.len += 1;
        let new_node = Node::from(data);
        if self.len == 0 {
            self.head = Rc::from(Some(new_node));
        }

        else {
            let mut curr_node = self.head.clone(); // Getting a mut reference to a Rc<Option<Node>>
            for _ in 0..self.len-1 {
                // Traversing the Linked List by going to the next node until we reach the end where we append the new_node
                curr_node = curr_node.unwrap().next.clone(); 
            }
            curr_node.unwrap().next = Rc::from(Some(new_node));
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut list = SinglyLinkedList::new();
    list.append(11);
    println!("{:?}", list);
}
```

When I execute it, I get the following error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of an `Rc`
  --> src/main.rs:84:29
   |
84 |                 curr_node = curr_node.unwrap().next.clone();
   |                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because value has type `Option<Node>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
   |
help: consider borrowing the `Option`'s content
   |
84 |                 curr_node = curr_node.unwrap().as_ref().next.clone();
   |                                               +++++++++
```

According to my understanding, I used `Rc<T>` because I would have 2 owners during the `append` function: One the Node before the a Node (could be self.head) and the other would be curr_node which I use to traverse the Linked List. I also need mutability and tried using `RefCell<T>` but couldn't get it to work. I do not understand what to do to not get this error.

Comment: You should probably be using `Option<Rc<Node>>`, not `Rc<Option<Node>>`. However, I don't think you even need `Rc` here -- `Option<Box<Node>>` should be sufficient.

Comment: Haven't read, but a mandatory link - https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```rust
curr_node.unwrap().next = Rc::from(Some(new_node));
```

This line will never work, not even conceptually. `Rc` is non-mutable. The only way to mutate an `Rc` is if the current `Rc` is the only reference to the data, then you can use `get_mut()`. But as you run `.clone()` two lines earlier, it's clear that this is not the only reference to the data.

So there are multiple ways to achieve that:

- In either solution, use `Option<Rc<...>>` instead of `Rc<Option<...>>`. You only need a reference if there is an item behind it, so having a reference to `None` is a waste of a reference and makes things a lot harder, due to the immutability problem.
- **Solution #1**: use `Option<Box<...>>` instead of `Option<Rc<...>>`, as @cdhowie pointed out. You only ever have one reference to the next item, so having an `Rc` is overkill. And `Box` is mutable, so no interior mutability is needed.
- **Solution #2**: If you want to keep the `Rc`, you need to add *interior mutability*, like `Option<Rc<RefCell<...>>>`.

I'll show both options.

---

### Solution #1

> I used Rc because I would have 2 owners during the append function:

The thought is not wrong, but we can use a reference to iterate through the items instead.

Also, minor fix: your `self.len += 1` was at the wrong position.

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Node {
    data: isize,
    next: Option<Box<Node>>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct SinglyLinkedList {
    head: Option<Box<Node>>,
    len: usize,
}

impl Node {
    fn from(data: isize) -> Self {
        Self { data, next: None }
    }
}

impl SinglyLinkedList {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self { head: None, len: 0 }
    }

    fn append(&mut self, data: isize) {
        let new_node = Node::from(data);
        if self.len == 0 {
            self.head = Some(Box::from(new_node));
        } else {
            let mut curr_node = &mut self.head;
            for _ in 0..self.len - 1 {
                // Traversing the Linked List by going to the next node until we reach the end where we append the new_node
                curr_node = &mut curr_node.as_mut().unwrap().next;
            }
            curr_node.as_mut().unwrap().next = Some(Box::from(new_node));
        }
        self.len += 1;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut list = SinglyLinkedList::new();
    list.append(1);
    list.append(2);
    list.append(3);
    list.append(5);
    println!("{:?}", list);
    list.append(7);
    println!("{:?}", list);
}
```

```
SinglyLinkedList { head: Some(Node { data: 1, next: Some(Node { data: 2, next: Some(Node { data: 3, next: Some(Node { data: 5, next: None }) }) }) }), len: 4 }
SinglyLinkedList { head: Some(Node { data: 1, next: Some(Node { data: 2, next: Some(Node { data: 3, next: Some(Node { data: 5, next: Some(Node { data: 7, next: None }) }) }) }) }), len: 5 }
```

---

### Solution #2

This is a possible implementation with interior mutability:

```rust
use std::{cell::RefCell, rc::Rc};

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Node {
    data: isize,
    next: Option<Rc<RefCell<Node>>>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct SinglyLinkedList {
    head: Option<Rc<RefCell<Node>>>,
    len: usize,
}

impl Node {
    fn from(data: isize) -> Self {
        Self { data, next: None }
    }
}

impl SinglyLinkedList {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self { head: None, len: 0 }
    }

    fn append(&mut self, data: isize) {
        let new_node = Node::from(data);
        if self.len == 0 {
            self.head = Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(new_node)));
        } else {
            let mut curr_node = self.head.as_ref().unwrap().clone();
            for _ in 0..self.len - 1 {
                // Traversing the Linked List by going to the next node until we reach the end where we append the new_node
                let next_node = curr_node.borrow().next.as_ref().unwrap().clone();
                curr_node = next_node;
            }
            curr_node.borrow_mut().next = Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(new_node)));
        }
        self.len += 1;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut list = SinglyLinkedList::new();
    list.append(1);
    list.append(2);
    list.append(3);
    list.append(5);
    println!("{:?}", list);
    list.append(7);
    println!("{:?}", list);
}
```

```
SinglyLinkedList { head: Some(RefCell { value: Node { data: 1, next: Some(RefCell { value: Node { data: 2, next: Some(RefCell { value: Node { data: 3, next: Some(RefCell { value: Node { data: 5, next: None } }) } }) } }) } }), len: 4 }
SinglyLinkedList { head: Some(RefCell { value: Node { data: 1, next: Some(RefCell { value: Node { data: 2, next: Some(RefCell { value: Node { data: 3, next: Some(RefCell { value: Node { data: 5, next: Some(RefCell { value: Node { data: 7, next: None } }) } }) } }) } }) } }), len: 5 }
```

Comment: Alright. I think I understand now. Please let me know If I am correct. Essentially, for solution 1, we get away with traversing the Linked List without having multiple owners in the first place? Only `curr_node` owns `self.head`? Also, in Solution 2, does `self.head` own the node initially, and then `curr_node` also own it? Moreover, who owns these `<Option<Box<Node>>`s in the first place? Thank you

Comment: Also, if I was to make a Double Linked List, I would *have* to use `Option<Rc<RefCell<Node>>>`, right? (Because a Node will be *owned* by it's previous Node AND also it's next Node, right?)

Comment: In the first one, yes, only the `.head` owns the first element, and `.next` then owns the next one. If we have a mutable reference to the first one, we can move the mutable reference to the second one as the first one owns the second one. This does not involve any ownership transfer. `curr_node` owns nothing, it only stores references. The ownership stays in `self.head` and  the `.next` members.

Comment: In solution 2, both `self.head` and `curr_node` own the elements. Due to `Rc`, multiple things can own the same object, but **only immutably**. Having multiple mutable owners would violate rusts borrowing rules. That's why we need interior mutability.

Comment: About Double Linked Lists: Yes, you would have to use `Rc`. But you need to be super careful to not create circular references. If a node owns its `.next` and the next node owns its `.prev`, that's a circular reference. Safe Rust does **not** prevent memory leaks. If you have a circular reference, memory will be leaked. That's one of the reasons why implementing your own linked list is so hard and discouraged. To get around that problem, you need to introduce `Weak` pointers in one direction.